# How to view MS To-Do's "My Day" tasks in MS Outlook for Windows

Tags: microsoft-outlook, to-do

In Microsoft To-Do, I can assign tasks to a "My Day" list.

How can I display (only) those tasks in Microsoft Outlook for Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the Task List using the following DASL-Filter:

```
%today("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{6F305800-7B8B-41AF-B73B-84DE53A69D3D}/CommittedDay/0x00000040")%
```

The information whether a task is assigned to the "My Day" view in MS To-Do is stored in the Property *CommittedDay* that contains a date. So filtering this property on today shows all the tasks that are currently assigned to "My Day" in MS To-Do.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this on my side. If I sign in same email account to Outlook client and Microsoft To-do, tasks that I added to My Day will also sync to Outlook task folder.

Comment: Of course all the tasks entered in Microsoft To-Do are also displayed in Outlook. The question is how to view explicitly those that are assigned to "My Day".