# How to view MS To-Do's folder in MS Outlook for Windows ("Important", "Assigned to Me", etc.)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, to-do

In Microsoft To-Do, I can assign tasks to a different predefined folders/lists like

- "My Day"
- "Important"
- "Planned"
- "Assigned to Me"
- "Flagged EMails"

How can I display those folders the same way in Microsoft Outlook for Windows?

HINT: [How to view MS To-Do's "My Day" tasks in MS Outlook for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1428502) did explain how to do this for "My Day", but how does this work for all other mentioned folders?

Comment: According to my research, Microsoft To Do does not currently support the start and end dates, task status, task completion percentage, multiple priority levels, task work hours, task colors, option to format text in notes, or categories that are available in Outlook Tasks.   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-microsoft-to-do-with-outlook-tasks-c7a0253d-b8cc-4054-b94b-c194e0e5308a

Comment: Hello @Aidan, I know that with the properties, but I did ask if it is possible to display the mentioned special folders/lists from MS To-Do in Outlook. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting functionality similar to "Search Folders" in Outlook e-mails, but in To-Do items. It is not currently there. But you can achieve at least partial results in two ways:

1. Create your own views of tasks (use first two items of menu **View**) which use filtering for given criteria. Anything except of "My Day" list should be doable. And "Flagged EMails" you can achieve by adding a Search Folder in e-mail section of Outlook.

   - Limitation: This will display only tasks in current folder (list).
2. Enter **Search** field (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and from newly appearing **Search** menu achieve filtering you need. This will search across all task folders (lists), if you choose to. Similarly, any common filter except of "My Day" should be achievable.

   - Limitation: This search cannot be saved. However, it can be preserved in **Advanced Find** window if you open it from the **Search** menu.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook 'To-Do List' is a built in list that contains all tasks (from all folders in the mailbox) and flagged emails.

If you create an Outlook Tasks view using the DASL-Filter string linked in the OP you can use it to filter the 'To-Do List' and see only see the 'My Day' tasks from all your To-Do lists.

The DASL-Filter string does not show the 'My Day' flagged emails though - looking for a property to filter those by...

The To-Do 'Important' flag (⭐) translates to the 'Important' flag in Outlook (❗)

'Planned' To-Do tasks will have a due date in Outlook.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).